# How to keep toggle buttons responsive across various screen types

Tags: html, angular

I have a toggle button in the header tab.On medium and large screens they are positioned fine like below

[medium and large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEDHQ.png)

But on small screens it is displayed as below
[small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HmoQ.png)

Below is my code

```
<div ngxRow>
  <div ngxCol>
    <ngx-radio-toggle>
     <ngx-radio-toggle-button>"1 Monat"</ngx-radio-toggle-button>
     <ngx-radio-toggle-button>"3 Monate"</ngx-radio-toggle-button>
    </ngx-radio-toggle>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to have this toggle button on the same line in all screens(small to big).The buttons should stay on same line even for smaller device and should not break downwards.Please help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this  for extra small devices

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
 .button-element{
    // you can resize your buttons here
 }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it is only increasing or decreasing the button size but is not alligning it together on small scrren